# Как создать обработчик сообщений для отправки сообщений в дискорде

Tags: многопоточность, discord.py, asyncio, pymysql, искусственный-интеллект

Дан данный код, который принимает сообщение -> заносит в таблицу для openAI -> в таблицу заносит ответ -> А далее должен быть написан код который возьмет это сообщение и отправит его в дискорд по channel_id

Естественно я пробовал написать, но каждый раз выпадает ошибка.

```
import random, asyncio, time, openai, discord, pymysql, threading
from discord.ext import commands

openai.api_key = ""
token = ""
intents = discord.Intents.all()

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(message.channel.id)
    print(client.get_channel(message.channel.id))
    con = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='Admin', password='Admin', database='open_ai', port=3306)
    cur = con.cursor()
    try:
        if message.author == client.user:
            return
        if '!бот' == message.content.split()[0]:
            if "" == message.content.split()[1]:
                return
            #Проверка на юзера в базе данных
            cur.execute(f"SELECT User_id FROM open_ai.user WHERE User_id = {message.author.id}")
            user_id = cur.fetchone()
            if user_id == None:
                cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO open_ai.user (User_id) VALUES ({message.author.id})")
                con.commit()
            #поиск переписки с ботом
            cur.execute(f"SHOW TABLES LIKE '{str(message.author.id)}'")
            table = cur.fetchone()
            if table == None:
                sql = f"""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS open_ai.{str(message.author.id)} (Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, Channel_id TEXT NOT NULL , Text TEXT NOT NULL , USER INT NOT NULL , Send INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0  , PRIMARY KEY (Id)) ENGINE = InnoDB;"""
                cur.execute(sql)
                con.commit()
            if cur.execute(f"SELECT Id FROM user WHERE AFK < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AND User_id = {message.author.id}"):
                response = ' '.join(message.content.split()[1:])
                sql, params = f"""INSERT INTO open_ai.{str(message.author.id)} (Channel_id, Text, User, Send) VALUES ({'%s'}, {'%s'}, {'%s'}, {'%s'})""", (message.channel.id, response, "1", "1")
                cur.execute(sql, params)
                con.commit()
                sql = f"""UPDATE user SET AFK = addtime(CURRENT_TIME, '00:00:30') WHERE User_id = {message.author.id}"""
                cur.execute(sql)
                con.commit()
                await message.channel.send("Запрос был отправлен на обработку в ChatGPT")
                cur.execute(f"UPDATE user SET Response = 0 WHERE User_id = {message.author.id}")
                con.commit()
                con.close()
            else:
                await message.channel.send("Перед следующим запросом подождите 30 секунд")
                con.close()
    except IndexError:
        return

def OpenAI():
    messages = []
    openai.api_key = ""
    con = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='Admin', password='Admin', database='open_ai', port=3306)
    cur = con.cursor()
    if cur.execute(f"SELECT User_id, Channel_id FROM open_ai.user WHERE Response = 0 LIMIT 1"):
        id, channel_id = cur.fetchone()
        print(id)
        cur.execute(f"UPDATE user SET Response = 1 WHERE User_id = {str(id)}")
        con.commit()
        cur.execute(f"SELECT Id, Channel_id, Text, USER FROM open_ai.{str(id)}")
        text = cur.fetchall()
        messages = []
        print(text)
        for Id, Channel_id, text, user in text:
            print(Id, Channel_id, text, user)
            if user == 1:
                messages.append({"role": "user", "content": text})
            if user == 3:
                messages.append({"role": "assistant", "content": text})
        print(messages)
        completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(model="gpt-3.5-turbo",messages=messages)
        chat_response = completion.choices[0].message.content
        cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO open_ai.{str(id)} (Channel_id, Text, USER, Send) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)", (str(channel_id), str(chat_response), "3", "0"))
        con.commit()
        con.close()

while True:
    con = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='Admin', password='Admin', database='open_ai', port=3306)
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SHOW TABLES FROM open_ai;")
    tables = cur.fetchall()
    print("f")
    for i in tables:
        if i[0] == "user":
            continue
        else:
            threading.Thread(target=OpenAI, args=()).start()
    time.sleep(1)
    con.close()


client.run(token)
```

Comment: Для начала выбросьте этот код и перепишите его полностью исходя из того, что базы данных не рассчитаны на то, что в них плодят много одинаковых таблиц. Вы же потом замучаетесь с ними работать. Думаю вам достаточно тут одной таблицы, которую надо создать заранее, от текущих она отличается тем, что в ней есть колонка author_id, Тогда ваш текущий скрипт превратится в единственный insert. А потом уже можно переходить к скрипту который будет читать эту единственную таблицу и решать посылать ли что то куда то

Comment: зачем мешать треды и асинкио? зачем тут sql?